# Create nested loops on behalf of a varaible

Tags: python, recursion, nested, nested-loops, nested-lists

I have a nested list of length n = 3

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

I want this result

```
[(1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

I get the result by:

```
ans = []
for i in a[0]:
    for j in a[1]:
        for k in a[2]:
            ans.append((i, j, k))
print(ans)
```

but if I change the length of a, I have to remove or add nested loops:

```
ans = []
for i in a[0]:
    ---
        ---
            ans.append((i, ___))
```

a simple solution is:

```
from itertools import product
print(list(product(*a)))
```

but I want to implement it manually

Comment: So you want to re-implement `itertools.product`? Then copy the source code - or use it, as it makes no difference at this point...

Comment: Recursion may be a good bet for this.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille - I think the [source code of the itertools module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c) is in C, not Python

Comment: The itertools documentation shows a python based implementation:
 https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a recursive function like this:

```py
def product(lst):
    for item in lst[0]:
        if len(lst) > 1:
            for result in product(lst[1:]):
                yield [item] + result
        else:
            yield [item]

a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
print(list(product(a)))
```

Output:

```py
[[1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 6], [2, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Note: if you want tuples, just use:

```py
print([tuple(x) for x in product(a)])
```

Output:

```py
[(1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```